# existing images are missing while deploying django project

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-deployment, django-dev-server, django-jenkins

when i am deploying the django project in jenkins, then existing images are missing in development server.

Many times am trying not issue is not identify.

for example picture.
[image: images are missing in development server]

please can you help it.

Thank you in advance.